# use context path in javascript for SockJs

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, contextpath

I am writing a chat app with Spring Boot web sockets and Stomp on the front end. Is there a way to programmatically access context root of my application in JavaScript?

my application.properties:

```
server.contextPath=/chatapp
```

my js

```
function connect() {
    socket = new SockJS('/chatapp/chat');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        stompClient.subscribe('/user/queue/messages', function (message) {
            showMessage(JSON.parse(message.body));
        });
    }
}
```

Now if I want to change application context in properties I will have to remember to change it in several places in the project which I am trying to avoid. So instead of hardcoding `'chatapp'` in js I want to be able to extract it programmatically.

I know in jsp one can access context path through ${pageContext.request.contextPath} but I am using thymeleaf.

Comment: well what I usual do is to access to the property in a Controller and write it in Model and then use it in the JSP

Comment: @AngeloImmediata do you mean you access the property in jsp, save it to a variable and it becomes accessible in your javascript? I thought in jsp you can use ${pageContext.request.contextPath} without updating the model in controller. Do you know how to do the same in thymeleaf?